# MKLocalSearchRequest for all businesses

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Another newbie iOS developer. I've got my code working to show local businesses by using request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Restaurants", but I want to return all businesses. I can't figure out what the wildcard character is. Seems like it would be so simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = 40.7056258
var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = -73.97968

var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
var longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01


var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)
var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Restaurants"
request.region = mapView.region
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that given the fact that this is the case for `naturalLanguageQuery`:

> This property can not be nil.

And no way is indicated to do a regex-based search, it's not possible. I'd check out another source of POI data for your task.