# How to get list of all nearby places within a given radius in Apple Maps

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I want to get all the nearby places given latitude, longitude within 250meters of radius.

I tried MKLocalSearchRequest API by Apple. However to make a request I need to provide a parameter naturalLanguageQuery which is a String (eg. "bank", "food", "salon" etc)

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "bank" // or "food" / "salon"
```

This returns area of interest of only a particular type. However I want a list of all the places in that region.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MKLocalSearchRequest for all businesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092087/mklocalsearchrequest-for-all-businesses)

Comment: You could create an array of all categories?

Comment: naturalLanguageQuery parameter is required for MKLocalSearchRequest and it cannot be nil.
What are other free source to get pointOfInterest? Google places API isn't free.